# When is a Frobenius Algebra a Quasi-Frobenius Ring?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $F$ be [Frobenius algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra) in the monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ of bimodules over a not-necessarily commutative algebra $A$. When is it true that $F$ is a [quasi-Frobenius ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring).

For example, this happens when $\mathcal{C}$ is Vect$_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: They are always.

Comment: What is a reference for this?

Comment: Also, are they pseudo-Frobenius, in the sense of

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Frobenius_ring